# Authentication using OAuth 2.0 and Multi user in HyperLedger

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have created and deployed Business network. I am Authenticating HyperLedger Rest Server using OAuth 2.0 github with Multi user enabled. I am to authenticate OAuth, but while Authenticating Multi user with card . It is throwing up following error:

Access Exception :Participant doesn't have create Access.

I am able to create asset without any authentication. After enabling Multi user, I am facing this issue. Any one faced similar issue.

Comment: hi there, I suspect you've not updated your `permissions.acl` (that is an ACL message saying the participant can't perform an operation in the business network). See an example for `trade-network` in composer sample networks as an example: https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/trade-network/permissions.acl  (its got system /network ACLs for (system/network operations) then a business network rule (allowing access by participants over resources in the business network itself).

Comment: More on ACLs is provided in this tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/acl-trading

Comment: Do i need to update ACL file after enabling Multi user mode ?While making transaction through Playground, I am able to transact . But, while adding order through Rest API multi user mode. I am getting access exception.

Comment: I have already defined that which Participant can access which resources in ACL file. whether these things needs to be changes. After implementing Multi user mode authentication?

Comment: `Access Exception :Participant doesn't have create Access` means: whatever participant you're using, is restricted by ACLs (I don't know what cards you are using in playground (is it connecting to the same business network - using the same business network card?) , and what happens if you try with Playground from another machine ?)

Comment: If I try to add Order asset using playground. I am able add it successfully. Reg-Cards- I am creating two participant and issuing ID and adding corresponding ID to card wallet. I am uploading same Cards using Wallet API to persist into Mongo DB. I am able to see the cards in Mongo Db. But, when I post using REST API to add the order . I am getting access exception.

Comment: `make transaction through playground` - as who? Is it the same BN card, that you're using on the REST API (that you've previously imported / setDefault to be the participant that's posting the 'asset create') when you are using multi-user / authentication?? Can you send - the exact screenshot - of the error - and the step or steps - you took immediately before - thanks